# Post Request not available inside get_queryset function inside ListView

Tags: django, post, methods

In ListView, I can easily use  **def post(self, request)** method to make a post request from a list view. But I want to make the post request from **def get_queryset(self)** which I am not yet able to do. When I try to do it it shows "**method 405 not allowed!**" even though post method is allowed through **http_method_names**.

How can I access POST request inside ***get_queryset*** function?

```
class ZonListView(SearchMixin, SingleTableMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'cadmin/list.html'
    model = Zon
    table_class = ZonTable
    search_fields = {
        'title': 'icontains',
        'description': 'icontains',
    }

def post(self, request):  # ***** this one works! ******
    try:
        toggle_status = request.POST.get('toggle-status')
        pk = int(request.POST.get('pk'))
        ....
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cadmin:zon_list'))

def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super(ZonListView, self).get_queryset()

    if self.request.POST:   #*****  Not working. 405 Error *****#
        try:
            toggle_status = self.request.POST.get('toggle-status')
            pk = int(self.request.POST.get('pk'))
            ......

    if self.request.GET:
        try:
            status = self.request.GET.get('status')
            qs = qs.filter(status=status)
        except Exception:
            pass

    return qs.distinct()

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    ....
```

Comment: Can you add the error traceback ?

Comment: Although this is not an error. It's just a possible feature I am looking for. Console shows: 

Method Not Allowed (POST): /admin/zon/
[27/Apr/2018 14:42:44] "POST /admin/zon/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make method allowed you need to implement function named same as method, post in your case. So to use `request.POST` in get queryset you also need to define `post()` method like this:

```
def post(self, request):  # ***** this method required! ******
    self.object_list = self.get_queryset() 
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cadmin:zon_list'))

def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super(ZonListView, self).get_queryset()

    if self.request.POST:   #*****  Now allowed *****#
        try:
            toggle_status = self.request.POST.get('toggle-status')
            pk = int(self.request.POST.get('pk'))
......
```

Look Django's `View` [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py#L104) to check how allowed methods defined.

Comment: I followed your way. Unfortunately, yet unable to execute the self.request.POST block.

Comment: Yes. Still, POST request can not be accessed from get_queryset method.

Comment: I have a doubt that get_queryset method is only executed on GET request! correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Ohid oh, you are raght! You need to call get_queryset from post method also! Check updated answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution is yet not working.  def get_queryset(self) has no access to POST request. Thus, Even on POST request if the get_queryset function is called, the line >>if self.request.POST<< is not being executed.

Comment: @Ohid are you sure you send POST request? I just checked it locally and it seems to work.

Comment: Hi thanks. I found my error. It worked. I put request.POST instead of self.request.POST.  thanks a lot